# Finger distance in music

Tags: word-request

When somebody is playing a piano they occasionaly increase or decrease the distance between their fingers so to reach farthest notes or closest ones. What are these two finger positions and actions called?

Clarification: when the fingers are very close to each other you can play notes that are byside each other. When the fingers are far from each other (depending on the hand) you can play notes that have a larger interval than a second.

Edit: I've noticed **"gather"** being used to get the fingers closer and **"stretch"** to get them further from each other. Would that be correct?

Comment: Spread (or stretch out), contract? Not sure

Comment: @laugh Neither am I. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Do you have terms for these actions and positions in your native language?

Comment: @SovereignSun What about [augment](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/augment?s=t) and [diminish](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/diminish?s=t)?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, **"собрать пальцы"** to decreas distance and **"развести пальцы"** to increase distance. And **"собранная ладонь"** when the fingers are together and **"развернутая ладонь"** when they are apart.

Comment: Spread is the term that is used in sports. I don't think that there is a specific term for moving the fingers closer together: that's regarded as the 'normal' position for fingers.

Comment: When I see the question, "What is something *called*?" I understand the questioner to be looking for a noun.  So you'd be happy with a verb? to ____ the fingers?

Comment: @Kman3, augment would mean add more fingers, or make them bigger or stronger... not move them further apart. In addition, augment and diminish have specific meanings in the context of music... check your definitions.

Comment: @JavaLatte How do you augment an interval on a piano without moving your fingers?

Comment: I believe the nouns  are **adduction** and **abduction**.

Comment: @Kman3, I see what you are getting at, but that meaning would only involve moving the top-note finger up. For me, it still doesn't come close to suggesting moving the fingers further apart.

Comment: @JavaLatte If you move the top note finger up, do your fingers move farther apart?

Comment: Having played cello for years, I think the spacing itself is not important rather the position you are trying to reach. As such, I don't think there is a specific term in general use for this, and I have never heard of one that I can recall. Maybe piano is different though.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Could you add some relevant definitions? I couldn't find anything offhand.

Comment: @user3169: "offhand"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I checked Collins but didn't do an in depth search.

Comment: @user3169. Ah, I thought you were punning, given the nature of the question.  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22abduction%20of%20the%20fingers%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A practised piano player's fingers can easily **span** an octave - sometimes more.

Comment: Most players can span at least a minor tenth, maybe a major tenth.

Comment: @ColinFine yes, but my answer was the usage of word **span**, not a comment on the player's ability.

Answer (score 0):

**adduction** - to adduct - To draw inward toward the median axis of the body **or toward an adjacent part or limb.**

**abduction** - to abduct - to draw or spread away (**as a limb or the fingers**) from a position near or parallel to the median axis of the body or from the axis of a limb

From Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary 11th Ed.

Comment: And can you adduce a single example of either of these terms in the context of playing the piano?

Comment: @Colin Fine [Google e.g. abduction finger piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0ASJZtNod4)